# Opaque Image/Shape Over Picturebox

Tags: c#

I'm pretty new to programming, so, I kind of (really) suck. I'm trying to read from multiple sources what to do and how to get around the restrictions of opacity, but I haven't been able to do anything.

I'm making a program that overlays a circle over a picturebox, and this picturebox changes the background image based on the selection in a combo box. I got most of the background done, (I just have to figure out the best way to deal with the memory problems of it stacking when changing options :|) but the cursor has landed me completely stuck.

Basically : I need to make a circle that is opaque/translucent, so that I can see the background image through it. Later on, I need to be able to move it with my mouse, so that would also be appreciated if the method used also supports updating the picture's location.

Currently I've tried -

[This workaround tool](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/201129/Change-Opacity-of-Image-in-C)

[Microsoft's guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s2dwfx1(v=vs.110).aspx) (Would this be the best method if I convert the picturebox background to a bitmap after the pb changes its image?)

Here's my Form1 code :

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MapList();
    }

    string apppath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

    public void MapList()
    {


        cBox.Items.Add(
            new Map() {Name= "Cache" ,
                Image = System.IO.Path.Combine(apppath, "de_cache_radar.png")
            });
        cBox.Items.Add(
            new Map()
            {
                Name = "Cobblestone",
                Image = System.IO.Path.Combine(apppath, "de_cbble_radar.png")
            });
        cBox.Items.Add(
            new Map()
            {
                Name = "Dust2",
                Image = System.IO.Path.Combine(apppath, "de_dust2_radar.png")
            });
        cBox.Items.Add(
            new Map()
            {
                Name = "Inferno",
                Image = System.IO.Path.Combine(apppath, "de_inferno_radar.png")
            });
        cBox.Items.Add(
            new Map()
            {
                Name = "Mirage",
                Image = System.IO.Path.Combine(apppath, "de_mirage_radar.png")
            });
        cBox.Items.Add(
            new Map()
            {
                Name = "Nuke",
                Image = System.IO.Path.Combine(apppath, "de_nuke_radar.png")
            });
        cBox.Items.Add(
            new Map()
            {
                Name = "Overpass",
                Image = System.IO.Path.Combine(apppath, "de_overpass_radar.png")
            });
        cBox.Items.Add(
            new Map()
            {
                Name = "Train",
                Image = System.IO.Path.Combine(apppath, "de_train_radar.png")
            });
    }


    private void cBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cBox.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            var imageName = ((Map)cBox.SelectedItem).Image;
            var file = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, apppath, imageName);
            pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(file);
        }
    }
}
```

Oh and my Map class:

```
public class Map
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }
}
```

Sorry if I've done this completely wrong or if the answer is glaringly obvious, I've self taught myself everything and thus don't really understand Bitmaps and Pictureboxes as well as I should (anyone have a good book I could pick up to deal with these graphics better for VS?)

Thanks!

Comment: Visual Studio is a IDE, it does not "run" or "Create" your program, it just helps you write it. You could just as easily write your code in notepad.exe and compile it from the command line with the tools built in to .NET. When talking about programming focus on "how to I do this in C#" not "How do I do this in VS".

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Sorry :P I changed the title, I'm a bit dumb

Comment: Your "in C#" is not needed either. You put that kind of information in the tags at the bottom of the question, not in the title (you can get rid of the `visual-studio` tag too)